# Open external link from web app packaged as native iOS app

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, web-applications

I have a link on my mobile app (created with Sencha Touch 2) with a `target="_blank"` attribute. The app is packaged as a native iOS app. The problem is, the link is not opening in Safari as expected, instead it opens inside the app. It is very important that the link opens in Safari in a new browser window. How can I achieve that?

I should add that I am using the native packager of Sencha (sencha package). The default behaviour seems to open the new window in the same webview. But I need them to be opened in mobile Safari.

In an Xcode project I could do the following:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

How to do that with Sencha Touch native packaging?

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your link"]];

Comment: Please read my post, I am talking about using the native packager of the Sencha Touch framework.

Comment: There is definitely a way to do this if you do not use the native packager.

Comment: Yes actually thats what I already had to do. But its not really an answer to my question. It would be great if there would be more options to configure the packaging process.

Comment: You can do this in sencha touch 2.1 with cmd beta 3: Ext.device.Device.openURL('http://url-to-open.com'); Source: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.device.device.Sencha-method-openURL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't discovered a way to do this with sencha native packaging.

But wrapping the application in a phonegap and compiling the application in Xcode, with required urls added to the ExternalHost array in phonegap.plist should work right?

Also, (still on the Phonegap solution) I assume hacking AppDelegate.m to open links in Safari would work just as fine.

Comment: I give you that bounty because you provided the best answer. I also think now there is no way to do this in Sencha Touch and I ended up on another problem to use phonegap anyway.

Answer (score 8):

I use this to open links in either Mobile Safari, or a new window. Works with Native iOS packaging and web apps:

```
function externalLink(link) {
try{
    Ext.device.Device.openURL(link);
}catch(err) {
    window.open(link, '_blank');
}
}
```

Comment: That's helpful but how do you invoke that function? I add HTML with links to an `Ext.Panel` and would want the links to open in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically (Javascript) opens a link in Mobile Safari.
Ideal if you cannot use a standard html  link but you must use Javascript:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute('href', facebook);
a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
a.click();
```